# How can I dynamically extend an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fuelux

This is an example of data to use for a jquery library, however my data is dymanic and not hard coded.

```
var tree_data = {
    'for-sale' : {name: 'For Sale', type: 'folder'} ,
    'vehicles' : {name: 'Vehicles', type: 'folder'} ,
    'rentals' : {name: 'Rentals', type: 'folder'}   ,
    'real-estate' : {name: 'Real Estate', type: 'folder'}   ,
    'pets' : {name: 'Pets', type: 'folder'} ,
    'tickets' : {name: 'Tickets', type: 'item'} ,
    'services' : {name: 'Services', type: 'item'}   ,
    'personals' : {name: 'Personals', type: 'item'}
}
```

So, My question is if I have this for example:

```
 var tree_data = {
        'for-sale' : {name: 'For Sale', type: 'folder'} ,
        'vehicles' : {name: 'Vehicles', type: 'folder'} 
}
```

How would I add

```
 rentals' : {name: 'Rentals', type: 'folder'}   ,
        'real-estate' : {name: 'Real Estate', type: 'folder'}
```

To tree_data after its already created?

I also need to do this for this code, if you could possibly provide an example for both.

```
tree_data['for-sale']['additionalParameters'] = {
    'children' : {
        'appliances' : {name: 'Appliances', type: 'item'},
        'arts-crafts' : {name: 'Arts & Crafts', type: 'item'},
        'clothing' : {name: 'Clothing', type: 'item'},
        'computers' : {name: 'Computers', type: 'item'},
        'jewelry' : {name: 'Jewelry', type: 'item'},
        'office-business' : {name: 'Office & Business', type: 'item'},
        'sports-fitness' : {name: 'Sports & Fitness', type: 'item'}
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at jQuery `extend` - it should be just what you need :) http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

Comment: So your question is 'how do I add properties to an object'?

Comment: @zeroflagL Guess so. I'm not from the javascript world. Last I checked you could ask some basics here at SO.

Comment: Do you get the additional data one after another or combined, like the original data?

Comment: @I get the additional data all at once, but it's not in the right format. I was thinking of adding it one by one through a loop but I'm open to better ideas.

Comment: check this: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/array_push.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using jQuery.... try using $.extend()

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

Otherwise...

```
var tree_data = {
        'for-sale' : {name: 'For Sale', type: 'folder'} ,
        'vehicles' : {name: 'Vehicles', type: 'folder'} 
};

tree_data['rentals'] = {name: 'Rentals', type: 'folder'}; 
tree_data['real-estate'] = {name: 'Real Estate', type: 'folder'};
```

Comment: Thanks, I got it working. I tried both methods and had the trouble with the jQuery one that I couldn't find a way to make the property name?(for-sale / vehicles) a variable, but I was able to put a variable for the name in tree_data[varName] so I got that to work how I needed it.

For the jQuery method, is there a way to name the propertyname be a variable? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Not that I know of.  More likely than not you'd have to use the variable to create a new object and then use $.extend() to join that new object with the old one, but if you're going to do that then you might as well just do it the way you're doing it now.  Glad to be of help.